# Grails: how to pass a array (and not a string!) using remoteFunction (ajax) from controller to view?

Tags: ajax, grails, gsp

I need to load different data  in a div when I change a Select option, not only a simple string but I list/array/map of strings. My code:

View:

```
<div id="contextMenu">
    <div id="testeDiv">${result}</div>
    <form class="selecionarConta" name="formulario">
        <g:select id="selecionaConta"
                  name="selecionarConta"
                  class="selectConta"
                  from="${menuDropDown}"
                  optionValue="string"
                  optionKey="value" 
                  onchange="${remoteFunction(controller:'dashboard',action:'teste', update:'testeDiv', params:'\'varteste=\'+this.value')}"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
def teste() {
    def result = [["Lemon":"${params.varteste}"],["Orange":"5"],["Grapefruit":"10"]] 
    [result:result]
}
```

Let's suppose I want to load an array or even an object in this div "testeDiv" and then any content I want, e.g. a list, or even a single element from this list e.g. `<div id=testeDiv>${result[1]}</div>`

Comment: and the point is: in this way, I simply can't print anything in mydiv.

Comment: Its hard to understand what you are trying to ask. What exactly you want to load on <div id=testeDiv>..</div> Can you provide a sample. Also, do you know about templates in GRAILS.

Comment: Sure! Let's suppose I want to load an array in this div and then any content I want, e.g. a list, or even a single element from this list e.g. `<div id=testeDiv>${result[1]}</div>`.